# How to properly construct prolog parser?

Tags: nlp, prolog, dcg

I'm writing a parser in prolog and getting the following error:

**procedure `copula_verb(A)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      proper_noun(A,B)
      np(A,B)**

My query is ?-np([the,cat],X).

Here is my code:

```
np([Word],X) :- proper_noun(Word,X).
np([Word|Rest],X) :- article(Word), np2(Rest,X).


np2([Word|Rest],X) :- common_noun(Word,X), mods(Rest,X).
np2([Word|Rest],X) :- adjective(Word,X), np2(Rest,X).


mods([],_).
mods(Words,X) :-
    append(Start,End,Words),
    pp(Start,X),
    mods(End,X).


pp([Word|Rest],X) :- preposition(Word,X,Y), np(Rest,Y).


sentence(Start, End) :- np(Start, Rest), vp(Rest, End).
vp([Word|Rest],X) :- copula_verb(Word,X), mods(Rest,X).
vp([Word|Rest],X) :- transitive_verb(Word,Y,X), np(Y), mods(Rest,X).
vp([Word|Rest],X):- intransitive_verb(Word,X), mods(Rest,X).


%  LEXICON

article(a). article(the).

preposition(in,X,Y) :- in(X,Y).
preposition(beside,X,Y) :- beside(X,Y).
preposition(with,X,Y) :- in(Y,X).
preposition(with,X,Y) :- beside(Y,X).

proper_noun(X,X) :- \+ article(X), \+ adjective(X,_),
    \+ common_noun(X,_), \+ preposition(X,_,_), \+ copula_verb(X),
    \+ transitive_verb(X,_,_), \+ intransitive_verb(X,_).

common_noun(cat,X) :- cat(X).
common_noun(box,X) :- box(X).
common_noun(basket,X) :- basket(X).
common_noun(poptart,X) :- poptart(X).

intransitive_verb(purrs,X) :- purrs(X).
intransitive_verb(sleeps,X) :- sleeps(X).

transitive_verb(chases,X,Y) :- chases(X,Y).

copula_verb(is,X,Y) :- is(X,Y).

adjective(sad,X) :- sad(X).
adjective(gray,X) :- gray(X).
adjective(white,X) :- white(X).

% WORLD MODEL

cat(Maru). cat(Grumpycat). cat(Henri). cat(Nala). cat(Pusheen). cat(Shironeko).
poptart(Nyancat).
box(box1). box(box2).
basket(Basket1).
in(Maru, box1). in(Henri, box2). in(Shironeko, basket1).
purrs(Maru).
sleeps(Shironeko).
chases(Nyancat,Nala).
beside(Grumpycat,Maru).
beside(box2, basket1).
beside(X,Z) :- in(X,Y), beside(Y,Z).
sad(Grumpycat). sad(Henri).
startled(Nala).
gray(Pusheen). white(Shironeko).
```

Could someone please explain how to get rid of the error?  I'm not sure how to properly structure a copula verb.

Comment: Please study [tag:dcg] first!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late by 10 months, but may help beginners in the future.

You have defined copula_verb/3 (with 3 arguments), but calling copula_verb/1 and copula_verb/2. So there is code missing (such as is/2).

In addition, under "world model", you define many facts using variables with capitals (e.g. cat(Maru).) This is wrong, since such variables are logically undefined in standard Prolog syntax.

I made some modifications and the answer to ?-np([the,cat],X). is

> X = maru ; X = grumpycat ; X = henri ; X = nala ; X = pusheen ; X = shironeko ;

Is this what you are looking for?

```
np([Word],X) :- proper_noun(Word,X).
np([Word|Rest],X) :- article(Word), np2(Rest,X).

np2([Word|Rest],X) :- common_noun(Word,X), mods(Rest,X).
np2([Word|Rest],X) :- adjective(Word,X), np2(Rest,X).

mods([],_).
mods(Words,X) :-
    append(Start,End,Words),
    pp(Start,X),
    mods(End,X).

pp([Word|Rest],X) :- preposition(Word,X,Y), np(Rest,Y).

sentence(Start, End) :- np(Start, Rest), vp(Rest, End).
vp([Word|Rest],X) :- copula_verb(Word,X), mods(Rest,X).
vp([Word|Rest],X) :- transitive_verb(Word,Y,X), np(Y), mods(Rest,X).
vp([Word|Rest],X):- intransitive_verb(Word,X), mods(Rest,X).

%  LEXICON
article(a). article(the).

preposition(in,X,Y) :- in(X,Y).
preposition(beside,X,Y) :- beside(X,Y).
preposition(with,X,Y) :- in(Y,X).
preposition(with,X,Y) :- beside(Y,X).

proper_noun(X,X) :- \+ article(X), \+ adjective(X,_),
    \+ common_noun(X,_), \+ preposition(X,_,_), \+ copula_verb(X),
    \+ transitive_verb(X,_,_), \+ intransitive_verb(X,_).

common_noun(cat,X) :- cat(X).
common_noun(box,X) :- box(X).
common_noun(basket,X) :- basket(X).
common_noun(poptart,X) :- poptart(X).

intransitive_verb(purrs,X) :- purrs(X).
intransitive_verb(sleeps,X) :- sleeps(X).

transitive_verb(chases,X,Y) :- chases(X,Y).

copula_verb(is).

adjective(sad,X) :- sad(X).
adjective(gray,X) :- gray(X).
adjective(white,X) :- white(X).

% WORLD MODEL

cat(maru). cat(grumpycat). cat(henri). cat(nala). cat(pusheen). cat(shironeko).
poptart(nyancat).
box(box1). box(box2).
basket(basket1).
in(maru, box1). in(henri, box2). in(dhironeko, basket1).
purrs(maru).
sleeps(shironeko).
chases(nyancat, nala).
beside(grumpycat, maru).
beside(box2, basket1).
beside(X,Z) :- in(X,Y), beside(Y,Z).
sad(grumpycat). sad(henri).
startled(nala).
gray(pusheen). white(shironeko).
```